# Not able to list the job using labels in k8s

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to list the `job` using `kubectl labels` but it's not working.

When I run `kubectl describe job/foo` I see the label defined as `job-name=foo` and then I tried to list the job using `kubectl get job -l job-name=foo -n foo_ns` but it returns empty field with a message `No resources found in foo_ns namespace.`

Later I tried to list the job using `kubectl get job/foo --no-headers` and that returned the job successfully.

I want to stick to the approach of listing the jobs using the defined labels. I need help in finding out the issue in my approach of using labels.

Comment: In all of the other commands, you haven't mentioned the namespace flag `-n`. could it be that `job/foo` is on the current namespace you're on and that's why you can't get any result with the `-n foo_ns`?

Comment: @Totem Thanks for pointing it out. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a job with [Labels](https://devopscube.com/create-kubernetes-jobs-cron-jobs/) .
Run the following command mentioned below:

$ kubectl get jobs --show-labels.